# Angular - change path to lazyloaded js file (production)

Tags: angular

I have an angular 7 project with module lazy loading and I want to customize the path to the lazyloaded file:
when I build the project (`ng build --prod`), angular takes care of everything and creates all the js files, including the lazyloaded module part in a separate file. It's awesome and simple, but I need to download the lazyloaded js file from a different server and need to customize the js file name.

I think the related code is maybe in `angular/router` (RouterConfigLoader.prototype.load for example), but I'm not sure, there is very less documentation on the subject.

Does anyone know how it works and how I can use my own code to manage the module lazy loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to host all the bundles and lazy modules on the CDN network under the same domain.

You can define the base path for the bundles on the CLI via the `--deploy-url` setting.

Here's a tutorial on the subject:

https://blog.chai-jay.com/angular-2-use-cdn-path-angular-cli-generated-index-html/

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer, but I need to have lazy modules on an différent domain. I think I have to overwrite some angular code to do that -> I try to find the code where angular is getting the lazymodule

Comment: @SergeL I don't think you can, because this is handled by Webpack.